# Show that $x_2x_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be $n\times n$ matrices, and let $b_1$ and $b_2$ be $n\times 1$ vectors. Show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $B_1=\begin{bmatrix}b_1&A_1b_1&A_1^2b_1&\cdots&A_1^{n-1}b_1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B_2=\begin{bmatrix}b_2&A_2b_2&A_2^2b_2&\cdots&A_2^{n-1}b_2\end{bmatrix}$. If you look at them as linear tranformations $k^n\rightarrow k^n$, $k$ being a field their coefficients lie in, you get $B_1e_1=b_1$, therefore $B_1^{-1}b_1=e_1$, where $e_1$ is the first vector in the canonical basis of $k^n$. Hence, $B_2B_1^{-1}b_1=B_2e_1=b_2$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Prove that $\pmatrix{b_1&A_1b_1&\cdots&A_1^{n-1}b_1}^{-1}b_1=e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$.